# Fetching genomic sequence efficiently in Python?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

How can I fetch genomic sequence efficiently using Python?  For example, from a .fa file or some other easily obtained format?  I basically want an interface fetch_seq(chrom, strand, start, end) which will return the sequence [start, end] on the given chromosome on the specified strand.

Analogously, is there a programmatic python interface for getting phastCons scores?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer to your question over at Biostar:

http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/getting-genomic-sequences-and-phastcons-scores-using-python-from-ensembl-ucsc

Use SeqIO with Fasta files and you'll get back record objects for each item in the file. Then you can do:

```
region = rec.seq[start:end]
```

to pull out slices. The nice thing about using a standard library is you don't have to worry about the line breaks in the original fasta file.

Comment: I agree that this approach is really elegant because you have a standard library to use but I found it to be very slow.  If you assume a fasta file with no newlines, you can simply "seek" the coordinates in the file which I think is much faster, and it doesn't require you to load all the fasta files from every chromosome into memory.  Is there a way to achieve the same kind of efficiency with a standard library like biopython?  thanks.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are looking for, but I agree that a custom solution tailored to your specific files will be faster than a more general solution. In practice most FASTA files have line breaks and what not, so I prefer being general but your experience may vary.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I'm hoping someone else will notice and bring up more recent news. 

Samtools (samtools.sourceforge.net) has a function called faidx that allows you to do exactly this on the command line. Pysam (https://github.com/pysam-developers/pysam) wraps many of the samtools methods, but I can't seem to get the faidx function to work. :P

At worst, I can wrap the commandline tool, but I'd like something "native" if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Retrieving sequence data from large human chromosome files can be inefficient memory-wise, so if you're looking for computational efficiency you can format the sequence data to a packed binary string and lookup based on byte location. I wrote routines to do this in perl (available [here](http://pastebin.com/mz5HFfyf) ), and python has the same [pack and unpack routines](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) - so it can be done, but only worth it if you're running in to trouble with large files on a limited machine. Otherwise use biopython SeqIO

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [biopython](http://biopython.org), which has support for several gene sequence formats.  Specifically, it has support for [FASTA and GenBank files](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc10), to name a couple.

Comment: It does, but I can see it only supports reading of records from FASTA, not fetching of sequences... if you wanted to fetch a sequence (start, end) from FASTA, you'd need a format with no new lines and the right interface and I don't think BioPython supports that.  Maybe I missed something though - could you point to the relevant doc on this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*pyfasta* is the module you're looking for. From the description

*fast, memory-efficient, pythonic (and command-line) access to fasta sequence files*

https://github.com/brentp/pyfasta